# Fusion Charts - Gantt Chart - Chart Type is not supported

Tags: fusioncharts

I am trying the trial version of Fusion Charts. I downloaded FusionCharts XT(v3.2.2) SR5 and FusionWidgets XT (v3.2) Service Release 2 trial versions, copied the scripts and flash files into my application, included FusionCharts/jquery.min.js,   FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js, FusionCharts/FusionCharts.HC.js, FusionCharts/FusionCharts.HC.Widgets.js in my aspx, I tried the below chart (Column3D) with sample JSON provided and it worked fine. i was able to see the chart.

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts("Column3D", "myChartId", "400", "300");
myChart.setJSONData(
{ "chart":
{ "caption": "Weekly Sales Summary", "xAxisName": "Week", "yAxisName": "Sales", "numberPrefix": "$" },
"data":
[{ "label": "Week 1", "value": "14400" },
{ "label": "Week 2", "value": "19600" },
{ "label": "Week 3", "value": "24000" },
{ "label": "Week 4", "value": "15700"}]
});
myChart.render("chartContainer");
```

But when i want to try gantt chart with sample JSON provided, I get Chart type not supported. Please see the code and complete JSON i tried below.

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts("Gantt", "myChartId", "800", "700");
myChart.setJSONData(
{ "chart": { "manageresize": "1", "dateformat": "dd/mm/yyyy", "outputdateformat": "ddds mns yy", "ganttwidthpercent": "65", "canvasbordercolor": "999999", "canvasborderthickness": "0", "gridbordercolor": "4567aa", "gridborderalpha": "20", "ganttpaneduration": "3", "ganttpanedurationunit": "m" }, "categories": [{ "bgcolor": "009999", "category": [{ "start": "1/3/2008", "end": "31/8/2008", "label": "Residential Construction", "fontcolor": "ffffff", "fontsize": "16"}] }, { "bgcolor": "4567aa", "fontcolor": "ff0000", "category": [{ "start": "1/3/2008", "end": "31/8/2008", "label": "Months", "alpha": "", "font": "Verdana", "fontcolor": "ffffff", "fontsize": "16"}] }, { "bgcolor": "ffffff", "fontcolor": "1288dd", "fontsize": "10", "isbold": "1", "align": "center", "category": [{ "start": "1/3/2008", "end": "31/3/2008", "label": "March" }, { "start": "1/4/2008", "end": "30/4/2008", "label": "April" }, { "start": "1/5/2008", "end": "31/5/2008", "label": "May" }, { "start": "1/6/2008", "end": "30/6/2008", "label": "June" }, { "start": "1/7/2008", "end": "31/7/2008", "label": "July" }, { "start": "1/8/2008", "end": "31/8/2008", "label": "August"}]}], "processes": { "headertext": "Task", "fontcolor": "000000", "fontsize": "11", "isanimated": "1", "bgcolor": "4567aa", "headervalign": "bottom", "headeralign": "left", "headerbgcolor": "4567aa", "headerfontcolor": "ffffff", "headerfontsize": "16", "align": "left", "isbold": "1", "bgalpha": "25", "process": [{ "label": "Writing", "id": "1" }, { "label": "Signing", "id": "2" }, { "label": "Financing", "id": "3" }, { "label": "Permission", "id": "4" }, { "label": "Plumbing", "id": "5" }, { "label": "Terrace", "id": "6" }, { "label": "Inspection", "id": "7" }, { "label": "Wood Work", "id": "8" }, { "label": "Interiors", "id": "9" }, { "label": "Shifting", "id": "10"}] }, "datatable": { "showprocessname": "1", "namealign": "left", "fontcolor": "000000", "fontsize": "10", "valign": "right", "align": "center", "headervalign": "bottom", "headeralign": "left", "headerbgcolor": "4567aa", "headerfontcolor": "ffffff", "headerfontsize": "16", "datacolumn": [{ "bgcolor": "eeeeee", "headertext": "Start", "text": [{ "label": "7/3/2008" }, { "label": "6/4/2008" }, { "label": "1/5/2008" }, { "label": "13/5/2008" }, { "label": "2/5/2008" }, { "label": "1/6/2008" }, { "label": "15/6/2008" }, { "label": "22/6/2008" }, { "label": "18/6/2008" }, { "label": "15/7/2008"}] }, { "bgcolor": "eeeeee", "headertext": "Finish", "text": [{ "label": "22/4/2008" }, { "label": "12/5/2008" }, { "label": "2/6/2008" }, { "label": "19/6/2008" }, { "label": "19/6/2008" }, { "label": "19/7/2008" }, { "label": "11/8/2008" }, { "label": "5/8/2008" }, { "label": "22/7/2008" }, { "label": "11/8/2008"}] }, { "bgcolor": "eeeeee", "headertext": "Hrs", "text": [{ "label": "150" }, { "label": "340" }, { "label": "60" }, { "label": "20" }, { "label": "30" }, { "label": "45" }, { "label": "40" }, { "label": "102" }, { "label": "60" }, { "label": "30" }, { "label": "90" }, { "label": "30"}] }, { "align": "right", "bgcolor": "4567aa", "bgalpha": "25", "headertext": "Cost", "isbold": "1", "text": [{ "label": "$4100" }, { "label": "$8290" }, { "label": "$12340" }, { "label": "$2330" }, { "label": "$4550" }, { "label": "$15720" }, { "label": "$1780" }, { "label": "$32330" }, { "label": "$9890" }, { "label": "$1110" }, { "label": "$1260" }, { "label": "$4260"}]}] }, "tasks": { "task": [{ "label": "Planned", "processid": "1", "start": "7/3/2008", "end": "18/4/2008", "id": "1-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "1", "start": "9/3/2008", "end": "22/4/2008", "id": "1", "color": "EEEEEE", "alpha": "100", "toppadding": "56%", "height": "32%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "8", "start": "22/6/2008", "end": "29/7/2008", "id": "2-1", "color": "4567aa", "alpha": "100", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "8", "start": "22/6/2008", "end": "5/8/2008", "id": "2", "color": "EEEEEE", "alpha": "100", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%", "percentcomplete": "78" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "2", "start": "6/4/2008", "end": "2/5/2008", "id": "3-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "2", "start": "6/4/2008", "end": "12/5/2008", "id": "3", "color": "EEEEEE", "alpha": "100", "isanimated": "1", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "9", "start": "18/6/2008", "end": "21/7/2008", "id": "4-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "9", "start": "18/6/2008", "end": "22/7\t/2008", "id": "4", "color": "EEEEEE", "alpha": "100", "isanimated": "1", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "3", "start": "1/5/2008", "end": "2/6/2008", "id": "5-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "3", "start": "1/5/2008", "end": "2/6/2008", "id": "5", "color": "EEEEEE", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "4", "start": "11/5/2008", "end": "12/6/2008", "id": "6-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "4", "start": "13/5/2008", "end": "19/6/2008", "id": "6", "color": "EEEEEE", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "5", "start": "1/5/2008", "end": "12/6/2008", "id": "7-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "5", "start": "2/5/2008", "end": "19/6/2008", "id": "7", "color": "EEEEEE", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "6", "start": "1/6/2008", "end": "12/7/2008", "id": "8-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "6", "start": "1/6/2008", "end": "19/7/2008", "id": "8", "color": "EEEEEE", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%", "percentcomplete": "91" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "7", "start": "11/6/2008", "end": "7/8/2008", "id": "9-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "7", "start": "15/6/2008", "end": "11/8/2008", "id": "9", "color": "EEEEEE", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%" }, { "label": "Planned", "processid": "10", "start": "11/7/2008", "end": "7/8/2008", "id": "10-1", "color": "4567aa", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "12%" }, { "label": "Actual", "processid": "10", "start": "15/7/2008", "end": "11/8/2008", "id": "10", "color": "EEEEEE", "height": "32%", "toppadding": "56%"}] }, "connectors": [{ "connector": [{ "fromtaskid": "3", "totaskid": "5", "color": "4567aa", "thickness": "2", "fromtaskconnectstart": "1" }, { "fromtaskid": "8", "totaskid": "2", "color": "4567aa", "thickness": "2", "fromtaskconnectstart": "1"}]}], "milestones": { "milestone": [{ "date": "7/8/2008", "taskid": "10-1", "color": "2E4472", "shape": "star", "tooltext": "Original moving date" }, { "date": "21/8/2008", "taskid": "10", "color": "999999", "shape": "star", "tooltext": "New estimated moving date"}] }, "legend": { "item": { "label": "Slack (Delay)", "color": "FF5E5E"} }, "styles": { "definition": [{ "type": "Font", "name": "legendFont", "size": "12"}], "application": [{ "toobject": "LEGEND", "styles": "legendFont"}]} });
myChart.render("chartContainer");
```

I dont think there is any problem with the JSON asi took it straight from the sample. But why am i getting Chart type not supported? Is there anything additional we have to do to make fusionwidgets work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because, JavaScript Gantt chart is not supported in existing offering of FusionWidgets XT.

Comment: Hey @jeevan, if you are interested, you can be part of beta testing if and when it is taken up. Do let us know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of FusionWidgets XT 3.3.1 supports Gantt chart in JavaScript flavor.

Refer for more info at: http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/13689-javascript-variant-of-gantt-chart/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [docs](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/gantt-chart) gantt chart

Gantt chart sample code

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var socialMediaPlan = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'gantt',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '750',
    height: '500',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy",
        "caption": "Social Media Optimization",
        "subcaption": "Typical Steps Involved",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "canvasBorderAlpha": "40"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
          "start": "08/01/2014",
          "end": "09/30/2014",
          "label": "Q3"
        }, {
          "start": "10/01/2014",
          "end": "12/31/2014",
          "label": "Q4"
        }, {
          "start": "01/01/2015",
          "end": "03/31/2015",
          "label": "Q1"
        }]
      }, {
        "category": [{
          "start": "08/01/2014",
          "end": "08/31/2014",
          "label": "Aug '14"
        }, {
          "start": "09/01/2014",
          "end": "09/30/2014",
          "label": "Sep '14"
        }, {
          "start": "10/01/2014",
          "end": "10/31/2014",
          "label": "Oct '14"
        }, {
          "start": "11/01/2014",
          "end": "11/30/2014",
          "label": "Nov '14"
        }, {
          "start": "12/01/2014",
          "end": "12/31/2014",
          "label": "Dec '14"
        }, {
          "start": "01/01/2015",
          "end": "01/31/2015",
          "label": "Jan '15"
        }, {
          "start": "02/01/2015",
          "end": "02/28/2015",
          "label": "Feb '15"
        }, {
          "start": "03/01/2015",
          "end": "03/31/2015",
          "label": "Mar '15"
        }]
      }],
      "processes": {
        "fontsize": "12",
        "isbold": "1",
        "align": "right",
        "process": [{
          "label": "Identify Customers"
        }, {
          "label": "Survey 500 Customers"
        }, {
          "label": "Interpret Requirements"
        }, {
          "label": "Market Analysis"
        }, {
          "label": "Brainstorm concepts"
        }, {
          "label": "Define Ad Requirements"
        }, {
          "label": "Design & Develop"
        }, {
          "label": "Mock test"
        }, {
          "label": "Documentation"
        }, {
          "label": "Start Campaign"
        }]
      },
      "tasks": {
        "task": [{
          "start": "08/04/2014",
          "end": "08/10/2014"
        }, {
          "start": "08/08/2014",
          "end": "08/19/2014"
        }, {
          "start": "08/19/2014",
          "end": "09/02/2014"
        }, {
          "start": "08/24/2014",
          "end": "09/02/2014"
        }, {
          "start": "09/02/2014",
          "end": "09/21/2014"
        }, {
          "start": "09/21/2014",
          "end": "10/06/2014"
        }, {
          "start": "10/06/2014",
          "end": "01/21/2015"
        }, {
          "start": "01/21/2015",
          "end": "02/19/2015"
        }, {
          "start": "01/28/2015",
          "end": "02/24/2015"
        }, {
          "start": "02/24/2015",
          "end": "03/27/2015"
        }]
      }

    }
  }).render();
});
```